# SAS proc http to get attachement from cloud server

Tags: rest, http, sas

I have written a simple proc http to connect to one of my cloud server instance.
I did get a 200 OK response.
But how to download a file that is present at the server via post(or in that matter via get) for proc http?

I am completely new to this web service connection part.
So can anyone guide me on this?

Code from the comments:

```
%let WorkDir = /*local dir name*/;

filename rich "&WorkDir\temp"; 
filename respns "&WorkDir\respns"; 
filename hdrout "&WorkDir\hdrout"; 

data _null_; 
file rich; 
infile datalines4; 
input; 
put _infile_; 
datalines4; 
payload={ "grant_type": "password", "username": "username", "password": "password" "text": "sample" } 
;;;; 
run; 

proc http 
url="/*my url*/"
method="POST"
ct ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
in=rich
headerout=hdrout
out=respns; 
run;
```

Comment: Do you have a link/URL to file directly? To meet SO rules please include what you've tried and what's not working. http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/18/using-sas-to-access-data-stored-on-dropbox/

Comment: Thanks.What I have done so far is :

Comment: %let WorkDir = /*local dir name*/;filename rich "&WorkDir\temp";
filename respns "&WorkDir\respns"; 
filename hdrout "&WorkDir\hdrout"; 

data _null_;
file rich;
infile datalines4;
input;
put _infile_;
datalines4;
payload={ 
     "grant_type": "password",
      "username": "username",
      "password": "password"
   "text": "sample"
  }   
;;;;
run;
proc http
url="/*my url*/"
method="POST"
ct ="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
in=rich
headerout=hdrout
out=respns
;
run;

Comment: The problem is how to add a parameter to fetch a file from server.

Comment: Add your code to your question via an edit. Can't read that as straight text...

Comment: Do you receive any errors? You'll want to use a GET request if you want to download something.

Comment: We don't know enough about the server to comment. Please update your question with more information. The 'parameters' you're talking about may need to be included in the `payload={` part of a GET request, but without further information we're even more in the dark than you.